# Coldfusion ORM and Hibernate Filters

Tags: hibernate, orm, coldfusion, filter, coldfusion-9

I ask you because I'm searching a useful solution to filtering automatically my entity collections.

Almost every one of my models have a property true/false called 'active' that authorizes or not an entity to be loaded. It's use only in front end.

After a lot of googling I found the hibernate Filter mechanism and it look like what I'm searching for.
But unfortunately I found no way to use it through Coldfusion except using autogenmap = true and modify manually the .HBMXML. 
I don't find this solution very sexy and I'm seacrching a better. Anyone ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<cfproperty name="unsoldArts" cfc="Art" 
            fieldtype="one-to-many" fkcolumn="ARTISTID" where="issold=0">
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WS5FFD2854-7F18-43ea-B383-161E007CE0D1.html

You may use `where=""` if you like, but my CFC usually needs to manage all entities even when it is not active.

Comment: Yes you'are right!
I'm sorry I've wrote this post too quickly. I would like to be able to turn off/on this feature programmatically. 
I thought at ormGetSession().enableFilter() and ormGetSessionFactory().getDefinedFilterNames() that allows to manage filters. But I didn't find the way to create it dynamically.

Comment: dynamically? Why don't you use the good-old entityLoad with filters?

Comment: Because I don't want to write these filters every time I do a query. The property 'active' exists for almost all models. And 'EntityLoad' doesn't accept filter when you're asking a single record with his PK. So, I want to forgot the 'active' property for all the application. And  I want to have the possibility switch on/off this filter when it's an administrator who make the request and he want to see the non-active records for debugging or preview.